# AX2012 Iterate list from assembly

Tags: .net-assembly, dynamics-ax-2012

We have created a simple dll which returns a collection (List) after a search.
In AX we have this dll referenced. Now i would like to iterate the result and post it in a grid.

I have a (inMemory) Table which is the datasource for the grid. This is is populated nicely if i fake the data by inserting records by hand in x++. However, i would like to have the result of assembly but I have no idea how to iterate it.

I've tried looking at the iterator, but i cannont get it to work that way.

Instantiating the search assembly and calling the search method:
(seems to work, no errors)

```
static public List Search()
  {
   NORISKWarehouseConnect.Client warehouseClient;
   List warehouseProductResultSet;
   ListIterator resultIterator;
   InteropPermission permission;
   ;

   try {
    permission = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::DllInterop);
    permission.assert();
    warehouseClient = new NORISKWarehouseConnect.Client();
    warehouseProductResultSet = warehouseClient.Search("search term");
    return warehouseProductResultSet;

   }catch{
    error("Error retrieving data");
    return null;
  }

}
```

And from my form i call the static above:

```
void clicked()
{
   List result = AARWarehouseConnect::Search();

   // iterate the result here?
   tempData.Code = "1234";
   tempData.Name = "blabla";
   tempData.insert();

   AARWarehouseProductDataSource.setTmpData(tempData);
   AARWarehouseProductDataSource_DS.research();


   super();
}
```

Thanks,
steve

Comment: Indeed you need to use a ListIterator or a ListEnumerator (recommended for most cases). Your code doesn't show your issue with the iterator as you don't use it, could you add what you tried? For reference, [ListEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/listenumerator.aspx) and [ListIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/listiterator.aspx)

Comment: You'll need to post some more code as passing objects between elements may be problematic with serialization and temp tables. The problem may be in a piece of code that we can't see.

Comment: Please *don't* put an *answer* in your question. Answers belong as, well, answers. And you shouldn't edit your title to say `solved` - the way that SO works, we know that your question has been answered satisfactorily when you accept an answer (as you appear to have already done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what exact type warehouseClient.Search does return.

If it is a .NET list, declare variable as System.Collections.IEnumerable and iterate using GetEnumerator.

An example for .NET regular expressions:

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection  matches = regEx.Matches(_source);
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match            m;
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection  groups;
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group            g;
 System.Collections.IEnumerator                  matchesEnum, groupsEnum;
 ...
 matchesCount = matches.get_Count();
 matchesEnum = matches.GetEnumerator();
 while (matchesEnum.MoveNext())
 {
    m = matchesEnum.get_Current();
```

Comment: Together with the previous answer I was able to use your example to get it to work. I've updated my initial question with the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the replies I got it to work the following way:

The class calling the dll returning an IEnumerable:

```
static public System.Collections.IEnumerable Search()
{
 NORISKWarehouseConnect.Client warehouseClient;
 System.Collections.IEnumerable warehouseProductResultSet;
 ListIterator resultIterator;
 InteropPermission permission;
 ;

 try {
    permission = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::DllInterop);
    permission.assert();
    warehouseClient = new NORISKWarehouseConnect.Client();
    warehouseProductResultSet = warehouseClient.Search("search term");
    return warehouseProductResultSet.GetEnumerator();
 }catch {
    error("Error retrieving data");
    return null;
 }
}
```

And parsing the result:

```
NORISKWarehouseConnect.Product product;
System.Collections.IEnumerator result = AARWarehouseConnect::Search();

while (result.MoveNext()) {
    product = result.get_Current();
    tempData.Code = product.get_Code();
    tempData.Name = product.get_Name();
    tempData.insert();        
}

AARWarehouseProductDataSource.setTmpData(tempData);
AARWarehouseProductDataSource_DS.research();
```